# Adding ints from to string to 2D array every Nth character

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, substring

What I am trying to do here is populate a 2d array from a text file. For sake of simplicity, I will keep this short and show you my problem. I have this following string:

```
string numbers = "11121314151617181920";
```

I would like to add this to an array every 2 Chars, so the array would appear and output:

```
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

I have gone about this using the Substring method available in c#. This is my code:

```
int[,] numArray = new int[1, 10];

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    while (i != 20)
    {
        numArray[0, x] = int.Parse(numbers.Substring(i, 2));
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

Edit: The output of this code gives me:

> 20000000000

My desired output is:

> 11,12,13,214,15,16,17,18,19,20

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn [how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Thank you for the link, will give that a read now!

Comment: Are you trying to output `11,12,13..., 21,22,23,...,31,32,33... etc` ?

Comment: If you were to step through this in the debugger it would become quickly apparent what your problem is. Hint: pay attention to the value of i throughout your loop.

Comment: @Haldo i've edited the question for my desired output.

Comment: @Chris thanks, looking into debugging now

Comment: Also are you sure the desired output in your last line is correct? It seems to disagree with your desired output at the beginning of the question (11-20 which matches the string as opposed to 21-30 at the end).

Comment: really sorry about that, edited again

Comment: I solved it btw, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I had the for loop in the wrong spot:

```
while (i != 20)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        numArray[0, x] = int.Parse(numbers.Substring(i, 2));
        i += 2;
    }
}
```